# How to call Api after userDetails data in React

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, react-redux

I have one problem how can i call the apis after getting the userDetails.
so i have one apis which is calling when user reload the page its call userDetails apis where we can fetch the data from db.

so once data is fetch from db then i need to call other apis based on userDetails.
but userDetails api calling from auth.js and i have to check in serval pages in view if userDetails there then call other api.

is there any chance to all other apis after fetching the user details.

i tried many solution but its not working.

i try to put async and await in componentdidmount but same problem its through the error userDetails null.

i added something like this,

`async componentDidMount() { if(this.props.userDetails !== null ) { ... others apis..}`

`}`

but is not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: One solution is to make userDetails API return a promise and then call the other APIs when promise is resolved.

Comment: Can you add related code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Check the userDetails props in componentDidUpdate whether if it has changed or not. So you won't call the api everytime component updates.

componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps) { if(this.props.userDetails !== prevProps.userDetails ) { ... others apis..}
}

Answer (score 0):

Please Try  with following code in your app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './main.css';
import Modal from './components/Modal/modal';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showModal1: false,
    showModal2: false
  };

  showModal = x => {
    this.setState({
      [x]: !this.state[x]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button className="toggle-button" onClick={x => {
            this.showModal(showModal1);
          }}>Show yourself Modal 1!</button>
        </div>
         <div className="button-container">
          <button className="toggle-button" onClick={x => {
            this.showModal(showModal2);
          }}>Show yourself Modal 2!</button>
        </div>
        <Modal onClose={this.showModal} show={this.state.show1} title="Test modal 1" id="1">Lorem ipsum</Modal>
        <Modal onClose={this.showModal} show={this.state.show2} title="Test modal 2" id="2">I am a different modal</Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```